# How to remove gap between two drawing points

Tags: ios, swift

Any body can help me how to remove this gap when we draw fast
Here is the image of the issue:

[image]

here is the code that we can use to draw on sand background using image pointer.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        lastPoint = touch!.location(in: ImageView)

        BindImageView(centerpoint: lastPoint)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let fromPoint = touch!.location(in: ImageView)
        //drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: fromPoint)
        BindImageView(centerpoint: fromPoint)

        lastPoint = fromPoint
    }

    func BindImageView(centerpoint:CGPoint)
    {
        //print(centerpoint)

        let imagview = UIImageView()
        imagview.image = UIImage(named: "b1")
        imagview.center = centerpoint
        imagview.frame.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 15)
        self.view.addSubview(imagview)

        let angle = atan2(self.lastPoint.y-(centerpoint.y), self.lastPoint.x-(centerpoint.x))
        imagview.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
    }
```

Comment: hi, welcome to SO - please add details, some code and generally be WAY more specific.

Comment: Is you app about recoginizing finger touches and then drawing according lines into the "sand"?

Comment: Yes defiantly drawing using finger touch

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following: You create a new image every time a "touch" moved, in order to follow the finger (and you rotate it accordingly). But the image "b1" is just a few pixels in width/height, whereas the distance the finger travelled between two `touchesMoved` events might be longer.

I would suggest to

- create a resizable image (either by code, `UIImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets:)` or within the assets catalog, button "Slicing")
- resize the image to reflect the real distance between two touch points

Nevertheless, if the user is "too quick" and draws "curves", the line you create with the images will still be somewhat angular and not bended. Therefore, it might be better to really draw a bezier path (and the shadow). This is quite more tricky, but also requires less resources than of creating `UIImage`s and `UIImageView`s over and over.

Comment: It's not that hard, you should try it yourself and post your code if you still observe problems: Initially, create a resizable image (the cap insets depend on the structure of your image, see documentation) and use this in your image view. Then calculate the distance between the last and current point (pythagoras) and resize the image view width accordingly. That's all.

Comment: Not working proper in this way. you have  any another way so please give me.

Comment: What does 'not proper' mean? Do you still have the gaps, our do you have problems with the `resizableImage` creation?

Comment: Yes, still we have face a problem